# Getting input from a browser - python + forms

Tags: python, html, forms, python-2.7

Working through LPTHW exercise 51 and hit a wall.  Trying to get some basic user input through a browser and then display it.  Code is as follows - first python:

```
import web

urls = (
   '/', 'Index'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

render = web.template.render('templates/')

    class Index(object):
        def GET(self):
            return render.hello_form()

        def POST(self):
            form = web.input(name="Nobody", greet="Hello")
            greeting = "%s, %s" % (form.greet, form.name)
            return render.index(greeting = greeting)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Then the HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample web form</title>
    </head>
<body>

<h1>Fill out this form</h1>

<form action="/hello" method="POST">
     A Greeting: <input type="text" name="greet">
    <br/>
     Your Name: <input type="text" name="name">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

When I click "submit" the only thing I get back is "not found".

Comment: Your form `action` attribute says it's going to the `/hello` endpoint but I don't see it specified anywhere in your Python code

Answer (score 1):

You have missed something important in your code in the Python file.

You should write this :

```
urls = (
   '/hello', 'Index'
```

instead of this :

```
urls = (
   '/', 'Index' ...
```